# Store a small log file as a blob in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I am utilizing a small sqlite database to keep track of some jobs that run on a linux box. Most of them have small (less than 50 lines) log files... I'd like to store those log files as a record in my database....

How can I get a text log file into my sqlite database? I want it stored as text in the record, not as a file.

Answer (score 1):

For me your last line contradicts the subject (blob vs text), so probably I mistook your idea.
But what about making your log file an `INSERT` statement on the fly?  Then feed that into your desired sqlite database.  I mean something like this:

```
$ cat test.sql
INSERT INTO test
SELECT 'something
anything';

$ sqlite3 test < test.sql

$ sqlite3 test
SQLite version 3.6.22
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> SELECT * FROM test;
something
anything
sqlite>
```